# Is there a benefit to successfully handling more balls in the bonus levels?

Tags: shatter

Bonus levels in shatter begin with three balls in an empty field that you must strive not to drop for as long as possible (and that's quite the challenge as they constantly become faster).

Since you gain 100,000 points each time you successfully hit one of the balls away from you, I don't really see an actual benefit in keeping all of the balls alive, instead of focusing on just one.

Theoretically, three balls allow you to gain points much faster as you simply have more opportunities to hit them away, but in practice I find that it just makes things more difficult, especially once the balls gather enough momentum and start ricocheting off of each other like crazy.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: you're missing the balls, by the sounds of it